# How can I determine if an array or series of variables occurs in sequence?

Tags: vb.net

I have 7 numeric values, zero or greater, sequenced by each day of the week. As few as one or as many as all of the values may be greater-than-zero. I need a way to determine if the >0 values occur in a SINGLE sequence.

For example:

```
0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

would be a single sequence while

```
8, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0
```

has two separate sequences and would therefore not qualify. I would also want it to be considered a qualifying sequence if there is only one greater-than-zero value in the entire grouping.

I have begun with a function that takes the 7 variables and stuffs them into a Boolean array based on whether each is zero or nonzero -- false for 0 and true for >0, which gives me something like

```
{false, true, true, false, false, false, false}
```

I now need to determine if the contents of that array contain the qualifying sequence per the above qualifications. Any ideas?

For what little it's worth, this is my function so far:

```
Public Function IsConcurrent(D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7) As Boolean
  Dim arr(6) As Single
  arr(0) = D1
  arr(1) = D2
  arr(2) = D3
  arr(3) = D4
  arr(4) = D5
  arr(5) = D6
  arr(6) = D7

  Dim concurrent As Boolean = False
  If CSng(arr(0)) > 0 Then concurrent = True
  For k = 2 To 7
    If arr(k - 1) = arr(k - 2) Then
    Else
    End If
  Next

  Return concurrent
End Function
```

Comment: Please show us your function rather than explaining it in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... I wrote this using `Lists` rather than an array, but the structure will be identical.

Here's how I did it:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim x As List(Of Integer) = {0, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0}.ToList

    Dim Test As Boolean = LookForSingleSequence(x)
End Sub


Private Function LookForSingleSequence(ByVal MyList As List(Of Integer)) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim RetVal As Boolean = False
    Dim SeqEnded As Boolean = False

    For i = 0 To MyList.Count - 1
        If MyList(i) > 0 Then
            If SeqEnded = True Then
                RetVal = False
                Exit For
            Else
                RetVal = True
            End If
        End If

        If RetVal = True And MyList(i) <= 0 Then SeqEnded = True
    Next

    Return RetVal

End Function
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it was first one and worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here goes the LINQ solution - fewer lines of code, and hopefully easier to understand:

```
Sub Main()
  Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)({0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0})
  Console.WriteLine(IsConcurrent(lst)) 'True
  lst = New List(Of Integer)({8, 0, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0})
  Console.WriteLine(IsConcurrent(lst)) 'False
  Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Function IsConcurrent(ByVal lst As List(Of Integer)) As Boolean
  Dim elementsAfterZeros = lst.SkipWhile(Function(x) x <= 0)
  If elementsAfterZeros.Count = 0 Then Return False 'we only have zeros
  Dim elementsInSecondGroupOfNonZeros = elementsAfterZeros.
                                        SkipWhile(Function(x) x > 0).
                                        SkipWhile(Function(x) x <= 0)
  If elementsInSecondGroupOfNonZeros.Count = 0 Then Return True
  Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I will be holding onto this!